# A program returns an error while importing a component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I created a new application with `npx create-react-app myapp` and installed all the components needed to run the application.

But, when I run `npm start` it failed to compile.

The application is really minimal, and I created a sandbox to test it, and it runs (starts and show a clickable text) with apparently no problem.

I also have the same 'offending' code running on another application, where it runs with no problem.

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-social-login-forked-dqui5?file=/package.json
```

Exactly the same code in the codesandbox, on my machine `(Linux, Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS)` returns the following error on `npm start`:

```
> kebrachatbotnew@1.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

Starting the development server...

Failed to compile.

Attempted import error: 'LoginSocialFacebook' is not exported from 'reactjs-social-login' (imported as 'LoginSocialFacebook').
assets by path static/js/*.js 2.1 MiB
  asset static/js/bundle.js 2.09 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
  asset static/js/node_modules_web-vitals_dist_web-vitals_js.chunk.js 6.94 KiB [emitted] 1 related asset
asset index.html 1.67 KiB [emitted]
asset asset-manifest.json 458 bytes [emitted]
cached modules 2.04 MiB (javascript) 31.3 KiB (runtime) [cached] 472 modules

ERROR in ./src/components/Login/Login.js 146:41-60
export 'LoginSocialFacebook' (imported as 'LoginSocialFacebook') was not found in 'reactjs-social-login' (module has no exports)
 @ ./src/components/Header/Header.js 4:0-35 50:12-17
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-48 20:35-41
 @ ./src/index.js 8:0-24 12:33-36

ERROR in ./src/components/Login/Login.js 180:41-58
export 'LoginSocialGoogle' (imported as 'LoginSocialGoogle') was not found in 'reactjs-social-login' (module has no exports)
 @ ./src/components/Header/Header.js 4:0-35 50:12-17
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-48 20:35-41
 @ ./src/index.js 8:0-24 12:33-36

ERROR in ./src/components/Login/Login.js 214:41-61
export 'LoginSocialInstagram' (imported as 'LoginSocialInstagram') was not found in 'reactjs-social-login' (module has no exports)
 @ ./src/components/Header/Header.js 4:0-35 50:12-17
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-48 20:35-41
 @ ./src/index.js 8:0-24 12:33-36

ERROR in ./src/components/Login/Login.js 250:41-59
export 'LoginSocialTwitter' (imported as 'LoginSocialTwitter') was not found in 'reactjs-social-login' (module has no exports)
 @ ./src/components/Header/Header.js 4:0-35 50:12-17
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-48 20:35-41
 @ ./src/index.js 8:0-24 12:33-36

webpack 5.68.0 compiled with 4 errors in 1540 ms
```

Can anyone help me to understand why the `import/export` couple could not run?

Comment: You should also show the code of the actual component that fails to compile. Btw, this is a tricky question, if you can't reproduce the problem, we can't really do much to help except with generic advice. Try going from a bare react app (which runs okay) and keep repeating steps you made until your app stops working. Then you'll either find the problem, or have reproduction steps we can follow in trying to help you.

Comment: I created the codesandbox above to show everything ....